# Backfeeding power to a SMPS from solar panels

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, solar-cell

Would anything bad happen if I connected the output from a 50 V open-drain solar panel to the the output (that's output NOT input) of a 48 V switched mode power supply?

Basically I have a boost charge controller that regulates charge to a big 57 V LiFePO4 battery.

When the sun is out the solar panel produces 50 V open circuit and 40 V peak power voltage.

The charge controller takes voltage above 40 V and boosts it up to charge the LiFePO4 battery.

When the sun goes down, for obvious reasons the charge controller stops charging the battery.

If I added an SMPS power source in with the solar panels that was on a light level sensor to fire up after dark keeping the boost charge controller charging the battery, is there any reason the power from the solar panel (max. 50 V) could do any harm back feeding to the output pins of the SMPS?

If it helps, they are JAM72S-20-460-MR-MC4-SM solar panels and an LRS-350-48 SMPS.

Thinking about it, the panels are 460 W and the SMPS is only 350 W so I would have to limit the boost controller's current to 350 W potentially wasting solar power, but if I purchased a bigger SMPS, would the principle work?

Comment: How about some diodes to prevent reverse current flow into the SMPS / solar panels?

Comment: with exception to the output caps, an SMPS circuit already contains its own barrier diode so I don't see why diodes would be necessary, i guess im hoping someone else could confirm that

Comment: Depends on the SMPS. Diode rectification, probably nothing bad happens. Active rectifier, probably not good. Get yourself a Schottky diode.

Comment: Switchmode power supply technology has long progressed past the point of secondary-side rectification diodes. At 350W, I wouldn't be surprised if that SMPS has synchronous rectification (and potentially even more exciting things on the secondary side). Some PSUs don't even start up if their secondary side has an unexpected voltage on it. There are diode types (ST "FERD" comes to mind) with ultra-low forward voltage drop that you could use.

Comment: ok, thanks, i will look into it in more detail, currently I have 10 panels and 10 boost charge controllers, having a separate boost controller for the SMPS from the solar panels would mean doubling the number of charge controllers that would get expensive, but a few diodes shouldent cost much.

Comment: It's feeding a battery which is like the world's largest cap. Why 10 boost charge controllers? How about put all the panels in series and feed them into one *quality* MPPT controller.

Comment: Why 10 boost charge controllers? I built the charge controllers myself, JLCPCB have a minimum PCB order quantity, I ended up with 10, I could re print the boards with duel input but i dont really want to wast the ones I already have so i would rather bodge mod the input

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be better to buy a solar controller that supports a power supply input and switches between the two automatically. But if you do this you need an or-ing diode solution at minimum. There are more efficient ways to do this with pmosfets also to avoid the diode drop.

Comment: I built the charge controllers myself, JLCPCB have a minimum PCB order quantity, I ended up with 10, I could re print the boards with duel input but i dont really want to wast the ones I already have so i would rather bodge mod the input. they will run up to 150v though im only using them at 50v input

Comment: i don't think a diode drop would be a big issue, at worst it would introduce a little inefishancy, but since solar power is free power anyway wasting a bit off free shouldent cost me much, buying a new charge controler would likely cost much more than free

Comment: i think my thoughts were more, would the diode even be necessary or would it work without, but then the response seems to be the SMPS may not like the backfeed

Comment: or-ing diode solution? the solar panels already come with reverse diodes built in to stop parallel panel leakage so back feeding them should have no effect?

Comment: Depends on if you have an MPPT tracker or not

Comment: charge is constant voltage tracking (technically not MPPT but wikipedia classes it as one of the MPPT classifications) the voltage is regulated to 76% of the open drain voltage with inductive PWM and then limited in current based on charge requirements, but as i programmed the controller this could be accounted for if required. its the SMPS i don't no much about its design

Comment: If you prefer the controller then find an smps that has an enable line and turn it on when the power gets too low, and shut off the mppt.